# Unable to slide down div tag individual

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a ajax page (search.js) attach to my main page and setinterval every 2 sec. In my main page, I have div tag (class="view") which able to slide down and cut off the interval. Everything work exactly fine but I have problem, when I click (*onClick="show()"*), all my div tag slide down togather. But my objective is to click and slide down individual for each div tag. I have try to troubleshoot but is not working due to lack of knowledge. Would appreciate if anyone can help me here. thanks alot.

```
 $allresponse = $_SESSION['allresponse'];
 $json = json_encode($allresponse);
 $db = json_decode($json,true);

 for( $i = 0; $i < count($db); $i++)
 {
    $data = $db[$i];
    ?>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; border-style:none; padding:5px;  border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-width:4px; font-size:14px; overflow: hidden; margin:0px 0px 5px 0px; ">

       <div style="float:left; margin:0px 5px 0px 0px; border:4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-radius:2px;">
       <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $data["companyIcon"]?>" width="49" height="47" style="border-radius:2px;"></a>  
       </div>

       <a href="#" style="color:#8080FF; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $data["productName"]?></a>

       <div style="float:right; margin:0px 8px 0px 0px;">
          <?php
          echo $data["City"];
          echo "</br>";
          ?>
       </div>

       <div class="view" style="font-size:12px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; border-style:solid; display:-webkit-box;-webkit-line-clamp:2; -webkit-box-orient:vertical; height:40px; border:2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-radius:2px; padding:0px 2px 2px 2px;">
          <?php
          echo $data["Description"];
          ?>
       </div>

       <div style="float:right; margin:0px 8px 0px 0px;">
          <div onClick="show()" style="cursor:pointer; font-size:12px; color:#8080FF; float:left;">Show&nbsp;<div style="color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; float:right;">/</div></div>
          <div onClick="hide()" style="cursor:pointer; font-size:12px; color:#8080FF; float:right;">&nbsp;Hide</div>
       </div>

    </div>
 <?php 
 }
```

search.js

```
 var Interc = null;

 function search_city()
 {

 var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();


 hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200)
    {

    document.getElementById("citybox").innerHTML = hr.responseText;

    }
 };
 hr.open("GET", "searchcity.php?t=" + Math.random(),true);
 hr.send();
 }

 var Interc = setInterval(search_city,2000);



 var Interr = null;

 function search_radius()
 {

 var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 hr.onreadystatechange = function() 
 {
   if(hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200)
    {

    document.getElementById("radiusbox").innerHTML = hr.responseText;

    }
 };
 hr.open("GET", "searchradius.php?t=" + Math.random(),true);
 hr.send();

 }

 var Interr = setInterval(search_radius,2000);


 var Interp = null;

 function search_product(){

 var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 hr.onreadystatechange = function() 
 {
   if(hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200)
    {

    document.getElementById("productbox").innerHTML = hr.responseText;

    }
 };
 hr.open("GET", "searchproduct.php?t=" + Math.random(),true);
 hr.send();
 }

 Interp = setInterval(search_product,2000);


 function show() 
 {  
 clearInterval(Interc);
 clearInterval(Interr);
 clearInterval(Interp);

 var $divView = $('div.view');
 var innerHeight = $divView.removeClass('view').height();
 $divView.addClass('view');

 $('div.view').animate({height: (($divView.height() == 40)? innerHeight: "160px")}, 500);

 }

 function hide() 
 {
 $('div.view').animate({height:40},500);
 Interr = setInterval(search_radius,2000);
 Interc = setInterval(search_city,2000);
 Interp = setInterval(search_product,2000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `show()` and `hide()` functions seem incorrect.

In `show()` it is odd, but legal to have a `$` for the first character of the variable `$divView` in JavaScript (it is normal in PHP). It looks like you remove the `class="view"` attribute from the `<div>` tags that have it set and then turn around on the next line and add it back. Presumably, you want to know the height when the tag isn't there, but I don't think it does a re-layout until *after* your `show()` function completes.

Try commenting out the lines that invoke `animate` and see if the size change happens instantaneously instead of over the animation period.

The `<div>` where PHP initially prints out the city, does not seem to have an `id="citybox"` attribute, but `document.getElementById("citybox").innerHTML = hr.responseText;` seems to expect one. Similarly the `<a>` tag where your product name is inserted by PHP does not have an `id="productbox"` attribute, but `document.getElementById("productbox").innerHTML = hr.responseText;` seems to expect one.

Also, won't you have a one `<div>` tag per database record with `class="view"` set? The code seems to only anticipate one such tag on the page. Or, do you only really expect to get a single row of JSON back from your database query?

Finally, I generally use `$.ajax()` rather than working directly with the browsers raw `XMLHttpRequest` object.